# my javascript freeze the screen and there is no mistake, just the navigator does not work

Tags: php, javascript, field, freeze, allocation

I met trouble with a script I have done,
this script should allocate an amount to different fields.

In fact here is the script, I will give you after the jsfiddle.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getItems()
 {
 var items = new Array();
 var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("items");

 for(var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++)
 {
     items[i] = document.getElementById("p"+(i+1)).value;
 }

 return items;
 }

 function setItems(items,payAmt)
 {
   //document.getElementById("troppercu").value = payAmt;
   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
   {
      document.getElementById("p" + (i+1)).value = items[i];
   }
 }

 function itemSum(items)
 {
var sum = 0;

for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    sum = items[i] + sum;
}

return sum;
 }

 function payment(inputElm)
 {
 var items = getItems();
 var payAmt = document.getElementById("montantacompte").value;
 var i = 0;
 var sum = itemSum(items);

 while(payAmt != 0 && sum != 0)
 {
     var temp = items[i] - payAmt;
     if(temp > 0)
     {
         items[i] = Math.round((temp)*100)/100;
         break;
     }
     else if(temp < 0)
     {
         items[i] = 0;
         payAmt = temp*-1;
      }
     i++;
     sum = itemSum(items);
 }

  setItems(items, payAmt);


 }
</script>
```

So I have an input in which I can write an amount, this amount will be allocated on the different fields.

Actually, the trouble is that when I put an amount that is the same as the principal amount, it freezes the screen. If I write the same amount + 1 cent, it does not freeze.

All information on the fields come from my database. that is written with PHP and MySQL.

http://jsfiddle.net/ywAU3/

The trouble comes when you write the same amount as in the principal so for that case it will freeze the screen if you write on the yellow box input 3654.58 I really do not understand why, in fact, it should not, because if I write 3654.59 all works, If I write more, it works also.

Comment: What is "xace"? I do not see that in your form.

Comment: I'm sorry, I write this too much quickly. I meant for that "case", I will correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in while cycle,

you have

```
if(temp > 0)
```

and

```
else if(temp < 0)
```

But what if

```
temp=0
```

That causes your while cycle to work forever... I included temp = 0 case and then code worked fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/ywAU3/2/

Comment: If you knew, I was looking ofr what hapen since 4 days. Thank you so much for the helo. Receive my utmost Respect.

Comment: Yes, but its not the underlying source of the problem. Just trying to help ya. =)

Answer (score 2):

The values you are passing into this function are strings, not numbers

```
function itemSum(items){
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
        sum = items[i] + sum;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The value of 'sum' is turned into a long concatenated set of strings, not numbers.

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you very much for this indication, In fact the troubvle comes from the wile that was infinite. I will also takes consideration of your indications

Comment: Glad to help. There were at least 2 reasons the loop wasn't ending, and its because since the 2 values being compared are strings that keep changing via concatenation, they always !== 0. Also, use explicit comparisons like === and !== instead of == and !=

Comment: I will try to correct it all, receive dear Sir my Utmost Respect. Kind Regards, SP